# Crystal Report how to hide image conditionally

Tags: .net, crystal-reports

On crystal report, I've to place logo based on price.
If price > 0 ,logo will not display, otherwise logo will appear.
How Can I do this?

I believe I've to write the formula against image subpress method. any idea?

please note image name picture1 .

Answer (score 0):

Just add a suppression-formula to the picture like following:

```
{YourTable.PriceColumn} > 0
```

Comment: I wrote it. {ReceiptHeader.isPayable} > 0
It says a statement is excepted here.

Comment: also when use crystal syntax, it says "string is required here."

Comment: Solved it. Thanks

Comment: Why didn't you already mention all that in your question? That usually happens if the `{ReceiptHeader.isPayable}`-column is not a number datatype.

Answer (score 0):

{YourTable.PriceColumn} > 0  and PriceColumn should be numeric tyoe.